# How does switch statements work in java 1.5 with string arguments?

Tags: switch-statement, java-5

Can i implement switch statements(by passing string arguments) in java 5 without making use of enums?I tried doing it using hashcode but i got an error

```
package com.list;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SwitchDays implements Days {

    static final int str = "sunday".hashCode();




    public static void main(String[] args) {


          Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);    
            String day= in.nextLine();

        switch (day.hashCode()) {

        case str:
            System.out.println(day);

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
            }


}
```

str in case str given an error:

```
case expressions must be constant expressions
```

Please guide.

Comment: You can declare str at the field level. eg. `static final int str="sunday.hashCode()";`

Comment: that also did not work

Comment: Show the whole class then, and why didn't it work? Eg. what was the error given?

Comment: check the updated code

Comment: Why not use an enum?

Comment: Ill agree an enum would be better for this, I am surprised that a `static final int` doesn't work and I feel you are leaving something out.

Comment: Actually, why are you even using Java 5? It's been EOL for about eight years or so. Even Java 7, which was released about six years ago, and didn't have any updates for the last two years or so, already supports switch-case expressions with string literals.

Comment: Okay, made an example, and the "sunday".hashCode(); doesn't evaluate to a constant.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `str` is referring to the expression `"sunday".hashCode()`, which is not a compile time [constant expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) as described by the JLS:

> A constant expression is an expression denoting a value of primitive
>   type or a String that does not complete abruptly and is composed using
>   only the following:  ...  Qualified names (§6.5.6.2) of the form
>   TypeName . Identifier that refer to **constant variables** (§4.12.4).

When you check the definition of constant variables:

> A constant variable is a final variable of primitive type or type
>   String that is **initialized with a constant expression** (§15.28).
>   Whether a variable is a constant variable or not may have implications
>   with respect to class initialization (§12.4.1), binary compatibility
>   (§13.1, §13.4.9), and definite assignment (§16 (Definite Assignment)).

Since `"sunday".hashCode()` does not meet this requirements, you get the error.

If you would change `"sunday".hashCode()` to a real compile time constant like `3` it would compile.

Answer (score -1):

The most straight forward solution is to make an enum, ie.

```
enum Days{
    sunday, monday;
}
```

Then it could be used as:

```
Day d = Day.valueOf("sunday");
switch(d){
    case sunday:
        System.out.println("ONE");
        break;
    case monday:
        System.out.println("TWO");
        break;
}
```